# Django mapping to Postgres citext array returns a str instead of a list

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a Django model with an array of aliases based on citext. When I retrieve a record, instead of a list `['foobar']`, I am getting a str `'{foobar}'` and obviously, trying to add an alias fails.

I used to have:

```
from django.db import models

class zone(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    aliases = ArrayField(
        models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True),
        size=4,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

That was working fine but since I needed to make it case insensitive, I changed the TextField to CITextField:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField, CITextField
from django.db import models

class zone(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    aliases = ArrayField(
        CITextField(max_length=255, blank=True),
        size=4,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

The result:

```
items = zone.objects.filter(name='foo')
item = items[0]
print(type(item.aliases), item.aliases)
>> <class 'str'> {"foobar"}
```

Any idea on why this *citext* would not be decoded as an array rather than a plain string ?

Comment: name is a CharField, aliases is the Array. I was about to replace name with a citext too but was stopped by this issue. `type(item)` was indeed `type(item.aliases)`, I had to anonymize the actual code a bit and missed one bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `django.contrib.postgres` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: Actually I am using Django 2.0 but since I upgraded from 1.11, there might be an older version lagging somewhere... Thanks for the great lead.

Comment: I upgraded to 2.0.4, psycopg2 2.7.4 (from 2.7.1) etc but it still doesn't work. This is really weird.

Comment: I tried out your models and could re-create your issue. I fixed it by adding `django.contrib.postgres` to my `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.